# How do I display device on map using mqtt?

Tags: cumulocity

I am trying to get my device appear on the map.
From the MQTT program I sent this message:

```
publish("s/us","401,14.118795,79.890456")
```

The location got updated on the "events" tab of my device settings:

```
DETAILS
Time 14 Dec 2017 16:40:09
Type c8y_LocationUpdate
Position { "lng": 79.890456, "alt": null, "lat": 14.118795 }
Date Time "2017-12-14T11:10:09.105Z"
```

But it doesn't appear on the map in device settings and in the cockpit. 
In the dashboard, I edited the map to include my device but it doesn't appear.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map plugin does not visualise the events but the position data contained in the managedObject of the device.

For MQTT this means you need to use the template 112 which only updates the managedObject or you use 402 which will create the event and update the managedObject.

The events are only used for the tracking view in device management.

Comment: Thanks. I published with 112 code and it updated the location.